# Unicode not displaying correctly using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
convert.onclick =
  function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < before.value.length; i++) {
      after.value += "'" + before.value.charAt(i) + "', ";
    }
  }
```

```html
<textarea id="before" type="text" name="input" style="width:100%;">*()-_=+ℚℝ</textarea><br />
<textarea id="after" cols="50" rows="10" name="output" style="width:100%;"></textarea>
<button id="convert" name="convert" type="button">convert</button>
```

Here's a simple code, and when I operate it, I get the following results.

[image: Problem]

Some letters have been converted successfully. But most Unicode characters are not displayed normally. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure all your unicode character have only `length` of `1`?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Converted to what?

Answer (score 2):

What you're running into are called [surrogate pairs](https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/unicode_encodings.html#utf-16-surrogate-pairs). Some unicode characters are composed of two bytes instead of one, and if you separate them, they no longer display correctly.

If you can use ES6, iterating a string with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) or `for..of` syntax actually takes surrogate pairs into account and will give you correct results easier. Other answers show how to do this.

If you can't use ES6, MDN has an example of how to handle these with `charAt` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt). I'll use this code below.

```js
function getWholeChar(str, i) {
  var code = str.charCodeAt(i);

  if (Number.isNaN(code)) return '';
  if (code < 0xD800 || code > 0xDFFF) return str.charAt(i);

  if (0xD800 <= code && code <= 0xDBFF) {
    if (str.length <= (i + 1)) throw 'High surrogate without following low surrogate';
    var next = str.charCodeAt(i + 1);
    if (0xDC00 > next || next > 0xDFFF) throw 'High surrogate without following low surrogate';
    return str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i + 1);
  }
  
  if (i === 0) throw 'Low surrogate without preceding high surrogate';
  var prev = str.charCodeAt(i - 1);

  if (0xD800 > prev || prev > 0xDBFF) throw 'Low surrogate without preceding high surrogate';
  return false;
}

convert.onclick =
  function() {
    for (var i = 0, chr; i < before.value.length; i++) {
      if(!(chr = getWholeChar(before.value, i))) continue;
      after.value += "'" + chr + "', ";
    }
  }
```

```html
<textarea id="before" type="text" name="input" style="width:100%;">*()-_=+ℚℝ</textarea><br />
<textarea id="after" cols="50" rows="10" name="output" style="width:100%;"></textarea>
<button id="convert" name="convert" type="button">convert</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use spread operator (`...`) to create array of unicode characters

```js
convert.onclick = function () {
 after.value = [...before.value].map(s => `'${s}'`).join(",");
};
```

```html
<textarea id="before" type="text" name="input" style="width:100%;">*()-_=+ℚℝ</textarea><br />
<textarea id="after" cols="50" rows="10" name="output" style="width:100%;"></textarea>
<button id="convert" name="convert" type="button">convert</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because starting from a certain point in UTF-8, characters can have length > 1.

```js
console.log("9".length);
console.log("".length);

console.log("".charAt(0));
console.log(String.fromCodePoint("".codePointAt(0)));
```

To fix it, instead of `charAt` use `codePoint` and `codePointAt`:

```js
convert.onclick =
  function() {
    for (const char of before.value) {
      after.value += `'${String.fromCodePoint(char.codePointAt(0))}'`;
    }
  }
```

```html
<textarea id="before" type="text" name="input" style="width:100%;">*()-_=+ℚℝ</textarea><br />
<textarea id="after" cols="50" rows="10" name="output" style="width:100%;"></textarea>
<button id="convert" name="convert" type="button">convert</button>
```

You can also do an index-based traversal, but that requires to increase the index varaible inside the loop, depending on the currently traversed character's `length`:

```js
convert.onclick =
  function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < before.value.length; ) {
      after.value += `'${String.fromCodePoint(before.value.codePointAt(i))}'`;
      i+= String.fromCodePoint(before.value.codePointAt(i)).length;
    }
  }
```

```html
<textarea id="before" type="text" name="input" style="width:100%;">*()-_=+ℚℝ</textarea><br />
<textarea id="after" cols="50" rows="10" name="output" style="width:100%;"></textarea>
<button id="convert" name="convert" type="button">convert</button>
```

Comment: Why to use `String.fromCodePoint(char.codePointAt(0))` if you already have single unicode char?

Comment: @Ponury Just for demonstration purposes, to make OP aware of these methods.

Comment: using `for..of` to iterate a string also makes the use of `codePointAt` redundant as it also results in surrogate pairs being accounted for

Comment: I do know that, but doing an index-based loop here would make things a little tricky since you would have to increase the index variable inside the loop, depending on the characters `length` property.